# How to trigger download failed error in php

Tags: php

On my site, i allow users to download videos, images (in chunks though), however, i want to make it in such a way that if a url parameter is not met, my download script should halt and cause download failed.

I did this:

```
<?php if(!$condition){
 trigger_error('Fatal error occured', E_USER_ERROR);
}?>
```

The problem is that, the file downloaded( although, currupted), when i checked into the downloaded file in a notepad, i saw my fatal error ("Fatal error occured").

How do i stop the file from downloading at all?

Comment: Respond with an error status code? Close the connection?

Comment: "*I want to make it in such a way that if a URL parameter is not met...*" What prevents you from checking the required `$_GET` param? What did you try? Show us any attempt you made.

Comment: @biesior yea. if(empty($_GET['user'] )) { //trigger stop }

Comment: `if(!is_set($_GET['user'] )) { die(); }` (or do some more advanced error handler)

Comment: @biesior using exit() or die() downloaded the file with but with zero byte. This worked: http_response_code(404)..Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CBroe .. Yea the error status  code worked. Thanks

Comment: "*using exit() or die() downloaded the file*" these two functions are equivalents and if it didn't stop your script from further execution, that means, that you have some logic mistake in part you didn't show us, after die()/exit() no any *next* part of code should be executed.

Comment: @biesior yes, nothing executed after the die() but the download manager downloaded it with zero byte...i.e just the filename "file.jpg" but zero byte...I don't know why though.

Comment: Looks to me, like you're sending content-disposition header **before** dying, hard to guess without seeing that part of the code. Just guessing.

Comment: @biesior well, above it is just my bootsrap file that contains functions and defined elements only and none is called and no echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put

```
exit();
```

inside the `if`, after you've triggered the error. This will halt the script execution so that any headers, content etc associated with the file does not get output.

Optionally you could also set an appropriate HTTP status code for the response.

Comment: http status code worked http_response_code(404); worked. Thanks

Comment: No problem. btw 404 is for "Not Found" which isn't really appropriate when, as in this case, the resource was found. If the request fails to supply all the required parameters that's a validation error and generally the most appropriate response to that is 400 (Bad Request)